# Who gets the credit for modified posts?

Tags: support, reputation, edits

I'm a new user of StackOverflow. I posted an answer to a question and then someone went in and modified my answer, cleaning it up and fixing a typo. That was very nice of them, not a problem.

What I want to know is, if this answer gets voted (up or down), who gets affected by the reputation?

Answer (score 16):

You're still the author of the answer - you'll get the rep.

The only exception to this is if the answer becomes a community wiki answer (which I believe can happen in response to it being edited many, many times), in which case no further rep is awarded.

Comment: Yawn, another upvote for Jon Skeet. ;)

Comment: I think Jon has more than enough rep and ought to let the rest of us have a chance at answering questions ;)

Comment: Don't worry. The problem will be solved by itself when the stack overflow happens (or int overflow for the rep :) )

Comment: I don't usually get rep for upvotes anyway. This answer has given me nothing so far.

Comment: I can't believe Jon got 100 rep for answering this

Comment: Eventually his rep will reach the point where his answers are automatically community-wiki'd.

Comment: No, it'll reach the point when his answers are automaticaly accepted and question closed :)

Comment: He already got his 200 today, so no benefit for him.  But he'll get 12 (?) when this gets accepted as the answer...

Comment: Each accepted answer is worth 15.

Comment: Each accepted answer is worth 25 in total.  If it's already been upvoted then you only get an additional 15 when it's accepted.

Comment: @Eric: You're assuming that the accepted answer is upvoted. Often it's not, and often the upvotes hit the cap anyway (which the acceptance bonus ignores). The difference between an answer being accepted and not being accepted is 15 - there's no point in conflating that with an upvote to get the figure of 25, IMO.

Answer (score 5):

Everyone else has hit the major points.  The only exception to this is if the person who modifies your post gets flagged as offensive, they will lose 100 rep, not you.

Answer (score 3):

You (original poster) do.

Answer (score 2):

If the post is community wiki, nobody gets any *reputation* for questions or answers.  The original poster still gets any *badges* that are generated from a community wiki question or answer.

There's a *lot* more information at the [SOFAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq).

Comment: If you have 65 badges, and Bill the Lizard has 65 badges, Bill the Lizard has more badges than you.

Comment: ...and Jon Skeet still has more than both of you...combined!  :)